# One-dimensional and multidimensional arrays in function parameters

Tags: c++

I'm experimenting a bit with one-dimensional and multidimensional arrays in C++ and passing them to functions as parameters.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t SIZE_ROW>
void printArray(std::array<T,SIZE_ROW> &arr)
{
    for (auto const &r : arr)
      cout << r << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t SIZE_ROW, std::size_t SIZE_COL>
void printArray(std::array< array<T ,SIZE_COL>,SIZE_ROW>&arr)
{
      for (auto const &r : arr)
      {
        for (auto const &c : r)
        {
          cout << c << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
      }
}
```

Can someone explain why the commented line doesn't work?
I'm a bit confused, since it seems that I need to pass the size of the array rows/cols to the function as well as the array itself, but the variant without passing the size does work and the other doesn't.

```
array<double,12> monthlyTemperature = {};
    
printArray(monthlyTemperature);
// printArray(monthlyTemperature, monthlyTemperature.size());
```

Thanks

Comment: The size is a template parameter here, so you can't pass it as a function argument. Why do you want to pass the size anyway? The function template will deduce it for you.

Comment: I'm new to C++. Well I thought I have to pass it. How should the function parameter look like, or is it correct?

Comment: The function can only take a single parameter, so you can't pass it a second argument. As I mentioned, you don't need to pass it the size.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, when instantiating a function template, the template arguments can either be specified explicitly or deduced through [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

```
std::array<double, 12> myArray = {};

printArray<double, 12>(myArray);  // Explicit
printArray(myArray);              // Deduced from myArray's type
```

You can also 'pass' some parameters with the above syntax while deducing others, for instance in this function that only prints out the first few elements of the array:

```
template <std::size_t FirstElements, typename T, std::size_t SIZE_ROW>
void printPartialArray(const std::array<T, SIZE_ROW>& arr) 
{
    constexpr std::size_t Size = std::min(FirstElements, SIZE_ROW);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}

std::array<double, 12> myArray;
printPartialArray<5>(myArray);   // T and ROW_SIZE are deduced
```